# Computed Prop or Data to pass to style binding for Backgound Image

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, data-binding, computed-properties

I am passing an object, every object has a string path of its Background Image. I have tried working with data and computed property, but neither of them works on the :style binding; however, it is working as a vue variable in text for example.

I have tried working with data and computed property

The following works.

```js
<div 
:style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + require('@/assets/images/cards/pic.jpg') + ')' }"
```

It is not working with data

```js
<div :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + require(imadata) + ')' }">

data() {
   return {
      imadata: "@/assets/images/cards/" + this.cardItem.image
};}
```

Neither with computed property

```js
<div :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + require(ima) + ')' }">

computed: {
   ima() {
     return "@/assets/images/cards/".concat(this.cardItem.image);
}}
```

Here is the error for the computed property:
*[Vue warn]: Error in render: "Error: Cannot find module '@/assets/images/cards/queryfox.jpg'"*

I expect to pass a variable to a Background Image src in style binding

Comment: Have you tried the path without the require() method? Like this:
<img src="../../assets/kpi_icon.png" alt="KPI">

Comment: Yeah, it works adding the path as you say; however, I need to retrieve it from a prop. The problem is that I am passing an object from the parent and all the information in the object is okay but the src in an image is not working

Answer (score 0):

Using img tag in a laravel vue application, you don’t need to add the require() or @/assets/. Just use the path of the  image or file as it is below

```
<img src="/image/test.jpg"/>
```

This will work just fine. For the case of your styling

```
<div :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + imadata + ')' }">
data() {
    return { 
        imadata: "/images/cards/" + this.cardItem.image 
    };
 }
```

This will do the trick